# How to automate dependency overrides updates with scala steward?

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-steward

Scala steward updates nicely all dependencies under `libraryDependencies` in `build.sbt`, but completely ignores `dependencyOverrides`. As we want our code secure we override dependencies with vulnerabilities with latest patched versions. For example new patched version of netty-handler is available, but scala steward doesn't create pr to update it:

```
dependencyOverrides ++= Seq(
  "io.netty" % "netty-handler" % "4.1.99.Final"
)
```

How to config scala steward to update those too? Suggestions with other tools are acceptable too.

Comment: Maybe open an issue on their **Github**? BTW, why not just depending on **netty** directly?

Comment: FYI, RenovateBot support this. (Scala Steward has other features that RenovateBot doesn't have though like scalafix upgrade rules).

Comment: Looks like RenovateBot is for gradle and maven, but not for sbt

Comment: It does work with SBT. Not sure where you got that feeling but we use it at my company for hundreds of SBT project without issue.

Comment: https://docs.renovatebot.com/modules/manager/sbt/